# Assertion error in Folium - “cannot render this Element if it's not in a Figure”

Tags: python, dictionary, gis, jupyter, folium

When I try to map the linked code below using the Folium package to generate clustered marker popups for a list of coordinates, I get the following error:

assert isinstance(figure, Figure), ('You cannot render this Element '
                                            'if it is not in a Figure.')

My strategy of clustering successfully runs through with no error. When I generate the map by actually calling on the map name in a separate jupyter cell, I get the error. I can't figure out a solution.

## MAIN METHOD THAT RETURNS CHOROPLETH MAP WITH POINTS

```
charterdropped.crs = sdshape.crs
charterdropped = charterdropped.to_crs(epsg='4326')
cjson = charterdropped.to_json()
mappo = folium.Map([37.7556, -122.4399], zoom_start = 7)

mappo.choropleth(
    geo_data=districtchanged,
    data=districtchanged,
    columns=['FIPS', '% Total Population: White Alone'],
    key_on='feature.properties.FIPS',
    legend_name='White people', 
    fill_color='YlGn',
    fill_opacity=0.4,
    highlight=True) 
points = folium.features.GeoJson(cjson)
mappo.add_child(points)


#Cluster Method

marker_cluster = MarkerCluster().add_to(mappo)
for each in charterdropped[0:len(charterdropped)].iterrows():
    folium.Marker(
            location=[each[1]['latitude'], each[1]['longitude']],
            popup=folium.Popup(
                            folium.IFrame(
                                html=each[1]['SCH_NAME'])


            ).add_to(marker_cluster))
```

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6ro0.png)

Comment: Try explaining yourself a little better.

Comment: Please add the code in the image to your question.  It will make your error easier for others to reproduce.